# Pentaho 7 CE System Error 0014

Tags: windows-10, pentaho

I have download Pentaho 7 CE edition and I have not been able to make it work. I have noticed that there is System Error 0014 that pops up in the log.

I have also downloaded Java jre1.8.0_131 and I am using Windows 10 machine. The following is a snippet of the error log in the tomcat.

```
20:39:08,993 ERROR [OSGIBoot] Error starting Karaf
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.framework/4.2.1
        at org.apache.karaf.main.util.SimpleMavenResolver.resolve(SimpleMavenResolver.java:59)
        at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.createClassLoader(Main.java:309)
        at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.launch(Main.java:229)
        at org.pentaho.platform.osgi.KarafBoot$4.run(KarafBoot.java:239)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.pentaho.platform.osgi.KarafBoot.startup(KarafBoot.java:247)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:443)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:434)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.runAsSystem(PentahoSystem.java:413)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:434)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.access$000(PentahoSystem.java:84)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:365)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:362)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.runAsSystem(PentahoSystem.java:413)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:362)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:332)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:228)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
20:39:09,001 ERROR [Logger] Error: Pentaho
20:39:09,005 ERROR [Logger] misc-org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem: org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.osgi.OSGIBoot
org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.osgi.OSGIBoot
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:370)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:332)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:228)
        at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.osgi.OSGIBoot
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:452)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:434)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.runAsSystem(PentahoSystem.java:413)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:434)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.access$000(PentahoSystem.java:84)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:365)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:362)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.runAsSystem(PentahoSystem.java:413)
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:362)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.osgi.OSGIBoot
        at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:444)
        ... 24 more
20:39:09,009 ERROR [Logger] Error end:
20:39:09,009 INFO  [PeriodicStatusLogger] Warning, one or more errors occurred during the initialization process.
Pentaho BI Platform server failed to properly initialize. The system will not be available for requests. (pentaho-platform-core 7.1.0.0-12) Fully Qualified Server Url = http://localhost:8080/pentaho/, Solution Path = C:\Program Files\Pentaho_BI\pentaho-server-ce-7.1.0.0-12\pentaho-server\pentaho-solutions
10-Jul-2018 20:39:29.970 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Pentaho_BI\pentaho-server-ce-7.1.0.0-12\pentaho-server\tomcat\webapps\pentaho has finished in 295,164 ms
10-Jul-2018 20:39:29.970 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Pentaho_BI\pentaho-server-ce-7.1.0.0-12\pentaho-server\tomcat\webapps\pentaho-style
10-Jul-2018 20:39:30.894 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
10-Jul-2018 20:39:30.910 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Pentaho_BI\pentaho-server-ce-7.1.0.0-12\pentaho-server\tomcat\webapps\pentaho-style has finished in 940 ms
10-Jul-2018 20:39:30.910 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Pentaho_BI\pentaho-server-ce-7.1.0.0-12\pentaho-server\tomcat\webapps\ROOT
10-Jul-2018 20:39:31.640 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
10-Jul-2018 20:39:31.656 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Pentaho_BI\pentaho-server-ce-7.1.0.0-12\pentaho-server\tomcat\webapps\ROOT has finished in 730 ms
10-Jul-2018 20:39:31.656 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Pentaho_BI\pentaho-server-ce-7.1.0.0-12\pentaho-server\tomcat\webapps\sw-style
10-Jul-2018 20:39:32.398 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
10-Jul-2018 20:39:32.414 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Pentaho_BI\pentaho-server-ce-7.1.0.0-12\pentaho-server\tomcat\webapps\sw-style has finished in 758 ms
10-Jul-2018 20:39:32.445 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
10-Jul-2018 20:39:32.632 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
10-Jul-2018 20:39:32.632 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 298043 ms
```

I would appreciate anyone help in resolving my issue.

Comment: check write access there for pentaho folder and subfolder

Comment: did you setup java_home?

Comment: Yes, I did setup the java_home

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by write access for pentaho folder and subfolder